# HTTP issue with redirecting

Tags: php, wordpress, sleep, redirect

When a user enters wrong data, I want the page to show a message for 10 seconds, and then redirect to Google. When I use this code, the page redirects to Google without showing this message properly.

```php
if($m==12 && $d==31)
    {
     echo "you entered wrong data"; 
     sleep(10) ;
     header("Location: http://google.com");
    die();
}
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: What language is this code in? You've left that tag out.

Comment: this is in wordpress with php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't respond to an HTTP request with a resource **and** a message that the resource that was requested can be found at a different URL.

If you want to redirect after a time period then you need to use a document level solution (such as `<meta>` or JavaScript).

For instance:

```
function redirect() {
    location.replace("http://google.com");
}
setTimeout(redirect, 10000);
```

That said…

People read at different speeds and people don't always pay continual attention to a given browser window (start something loading and then switching to another tab is not uncommon).

I tend to work to the rule of thumb that if a message is worth displaying to the user, then it is worth displaying until they actively dismiss it.

```
<p> you entered wrong data </p>
<p> <a href="http://google.com/">continue</a> </p>
```

Comment: Or he could just send a `Refresh` header i.e. `Refresh: 10;url=http://google.com`?